# Firebird 2.5 changes value of FLOAT field

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a Firebird database with lots of fields of type FLOAT. I've noticed strange behaviour when storing bigger values. When I execute

```
UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET SOME_FIELD=2361431.70
```

value is changing to 2361431.75. Field changes with other values but not with small ones. This is really surprising. I use this type of field all over my databases. I thought about changing field type to DECIMAL or NUMERIC but this is quite difficult on working databases with many float fields

Comment: Float is approximate numeric, as usually.

Comment: If you want exact values, don't use `float`: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Most implementations of `float` are only accurate to 7 or 8 decimal places.  That's how `float` is able to represent values between 10^308 and 10^-308 while only having 64 bits of information (which only has about 10^19 possible values).

Comment: Thanks a lot . So the only thing I can do is to create new domain DECIMAL(15,4) and change all FLOAT fields to this domain

Comment: If switching from float to numeric is hard to do, consider going from float to double precision. It won't remove these problems, but it gives you a bit more precision (32 bits more to be precise ;).

Comment: I guess there is no difference in changing field type to numeric or DP. Both require the same effort :)

Comment: Yes, both require effort, but changing from `float` to `double precision` can be done with altering the column, while going from `float` to `numeric` or `decimal` requires creating a new column, transferring the value, dropping the old column and renaming the column.

Comment: I have done this by creating new numeric domain and changing field source in RDB$RELATION_FIELDS. Thank you

Comment: Just a heads up: system table manipulation won't be available in future Firebird versions (and to be honest, I am not sure just changing the domain like this is going to work correctly).

Comment: Well. It worked for my databases. I suppose if in future this won't be possible I will change it by creating new temp column and transferring data between them. But this will much more time consuming. Thanks